# How can I refresh the data in a handlebars view?

Tags: node.js, handlebars.js, ejs, express-handlebars

I am working on a project, part of which displays notifications to the user. I have an object which is used to store notifications, and a table in which notifications are displayed. The notifications are written to a JSON file in a proper format for later use.

Currently the way things are, the object has new notifications pushed to it every x seconds, but the actual table only displays the new messages when  the page has been reloaded.

#### I am looking for:

- A way to programmatically refresh the data maintained within the table every x seconds.

  #### Or:
- A method like webhooks or socket that I can use to send the new object direct to the client.
- A method of refreshing the web page every x seconds, without the use of a module like nodemon, which actually kills and resets my server completely.

#### The JSON File

```
[
  {
    "Notification": "Limit Exceeded. Event has occurred. Action needed.",
    "Time": "19:54:34",
    "Date": "Sun Oct 28 2018 "
  },
  {
    "Notification": "Limit Exceeded. Event has occurred. Action needed.",
    "Time": "19:54:34",
    "Date": "Sun Oct 28 2018 "
  }
]
```

The JSON file starts empty, and has notifications logged to it. The notifications are pulled from here, and stored in an empty notifications object.

#### The Handlebars View.

```
<h2 class="page-header">Notifications</h2>
<h2>{{log}}</h2>
<p>Your Latest Notifications can be Found Below.</p>

{{#if notifications}}
    <table style="width:100%" border="1">
      <tr>
        <th>Notification:</th>
        <th>Time:</th>
        <th>Date:</th>
      </tr>
        {{#each notifications}}
            <tr>
                <td>{{[Notification]}}</td>
                <td>{{Time}}</td>
                <td>{{Date}}</td>


            </tr>
        {{/each}}
    </table>
{{else}}
    <h3>No Current Notifications</h3>
{{/if}}

<form method="post" action="/test/notify" id="removeuserform">
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Reload page.</button>
</form>
```

And the page of course is rendered using the following line.

```
    res.render('home', {notifications: notifications});
```

#### The solution?

I have looked into many a method here, and would love to see your opinions as well. I have seen people use webhooks, I have seen people initialize a button click which redirects to the same page. I cannot use the window.reload function. I have seen people place  tags in EJS views, but I am using Handlebars.

Is there a way to simply refresh the data in this notifications object when I push new items into the object? Any ideas you have are greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to care about 2 parts:

1, Get data from server in real-time via socket. Here you have 3 options:

- SocketIO or similar Node.js package
- A service such as [Pusher](https://pusher.com/), [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/)...
- A database that support data syncing, such as [PouchDB](https://pouchdb.com/), [Gun](https://gun.eco/), etc

2, Sync data from JavaScript object to view. This calls data binding. Basically, you have a JS object that contains your notifications. And you render that data to HTML, display them to end-user. When that JS object changes, your HTML should be automatically updated. That's one-way binding, from JS object to DOM (model to view). Many UI frameworks or libraries can help you here. You may choose a small tool, such as [HyperApp](https://github.com/jorgebucaran/hyperapp), [AppRun](https://github.com/yysun/apprun), [Mithrill](https://mithril.js.org/), etc.

Comment: Thank you @dong Nguyen, I will give that a looksie, but I was kind of hoping someone might actually be able to give an example or how to use any one of the packages you mentioned to achieve my goal, rather than just to use one of them haha.

If you have no experience with the modules, that is fine, I will be checking all of them out now.

Comment: Pusher looks like an interesting option for pushing new data. not sure why I will be needed both of these options though.